# entity &lt; is not working in xslt and cant find fields in less than cond

Tags: xml, xslt

i linked xslt file with xml.. in  for this code its showing error
Error in XSLT
Line 57: The character '<' cannot be used in an attribute value.

but for this code its showing error..
I used IE9.can anyone help me to use "<" in xslt..

Comment: "<xsl:if test="price &lt; 10">" this is the code

Answer (score 0):

Use `&lt;` - exactly like that.

Comment: Can you paste your XSLT? At least line 57?

Comment: <xsl:for-each select="customer">
 <xsl:if test="bal &lt; 10000 ">
      <tr>
 <td><xsl:value-of select="acc_no"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="acc_name"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="acc_type"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="bal"/></td>    
  </tr>
 </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </table>

</div>

</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
 that condition.. <xsl:if> check that

Comment: It should be OK - are you processing this XSLT? What does IE9 has to do with that?